# Snowflake - Extract values from variant data and concatenate

Tags: sql, json, split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below variant data in one of the column. Using snowflake query I need to extract the value part from this input and store that in the output column.

Input:

```
[
    {
        "id": "123456",
        "outwardIssue": {
            "fields": {
                "type": {
                    "avatarId": 500,
                    "description": "",
                    "iconUrl": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/secure/",
                    "id": "99990",
                    "name": "Opportunity",
                    "self": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/",
                    "subtask": false
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "",
                    "iconUrl": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/images/icons/statuses/trash.png",
                    "id": "567890",
                    "name": "CANCELLED",
                    "self": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/",
                    "statusCategory": {
                        "colorName": "green",
                        "id": 3,
                        "key": "done",
                        "name": "Done",
                        "self": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/"
                    }
                },
                "summary": "HHH"
            },
            "id": "234213",
            "key": "PPP-9169",
            "self": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com"
        },
        "self": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/issueLink/123456",
        "type": {
            "id": "10000",
            "inward": "is cloned by",
            "name": "Cloners",
            "outward": "was cloned from",
            "self": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/issueLinkType/10000"
        }
    }
]
```

Output Column:

```
[[123456,, [[[500, , https://bbbb.nnnn.com/secure/, 99990, Opportunity, https://bbbb.nnnn.com/, false], [, https://bbbb.nnnn.com/images/icons/statuses/trash.png, 567890, CANCELLED, https://bbbb.nnnn.com/, [green, 3, done, Done, https://bbbb.nnnn.com/]], HHH], 234213, PPP-9169, https://bbbb.nnnn.com], https://bbbb.nnnn.com/issueLink/123456, [10000, is cloned by, Cloners, was cloned from, https://bbbb.nnnn.com/issueLinkType/10000]]]
```

I tried the code like below but unable to get the desired output.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    '[[',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'id":"', 2), '"', 1), '{', ''), '"', ''),
    ',,',
    '[[[',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'avatarId":', 2), ',"', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ', ,',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'iconUrl":"', 2), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'name":"', 2), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'self":"', 2), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'subtask":', 2), '}', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    '],[',
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'iconUrl":"', 3), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'id":"', 3), '"', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'name":"', 3), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'self":"', 3), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    '[[[',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'colorName":"', 4), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'id":', 4), ',', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'key":"', 4), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'name":"', 4), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'self":"', 4), '}}', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ']],',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'summary":"', 2), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    '],',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'id":"', 3), '"', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'key":"', 3), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'self":"', 3), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    '],',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'id":"', 1), '"', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'inward":"', 1), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'name":"', 1), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'outward":"', 1), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ',',
    REPLACE(REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(SPLIT_PART(column_name, 'self":"', 1), '",', 1), ',', ''), '"', ''),
    ']]]'
  ) AS result
FROM my_table;
```

I am unable to get the proper output as above, and it looks complex to achieve or read. Please let me know if there are any other methods to achieve the above output in snowflake.

P.S. The input structure/order of keys remains same for all input columns. Output structure also same for all data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is valid JSON so, you should be using the JSON [semi-structured data functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/sql-reference/functions-semistructured) to pull this apart

But to show you the first step:

I have used a CTE to take the JSON and parse this string into a VARAINT:

```
with data as (
select parse_json('[
    {
        "id": "123456",
        "outwardIssue": {
            "fields": {
                "type": {
                    "avatarId": 500,
                    "description": "",
                    "iconUrl": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/secure/",
                    "id": "99990",
                    "name": "Opportunity",
                    "self": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/",
                    "subtask": false
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "",
                    "iconUrl": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/images/icons/statuses/trash.png",
                    "id": "567890",
                    "name": "CANCELLED",
                    "self": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/",
                    "statusCategory": {
                        "colorName": "green",
                        "id": 3,
                        "key": "done",
                        "name": "Done",
                        "self": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/"
                    }
                },
                "summary": "HHH"
            },
            "id": "234213",
            "key": "PPP-9169",
            "self": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com"
        },
        "self": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/issueLink/123456",
        "type": {
            "id": "10000",
            "inward": "is cloned by",
            "name": "Cloners",
            "outward": "was cloned from",
            "self": "https://bbbb.nnnn.com/issueLinkType/10000"
        }
    }
]') as j
)
```

now as you note, "all data is the same", we can directly access inside the first array and start pulling out the tokens we want:

```
select  
    try_to_number(j[0]:id::text) as id,
    j[0]:outwardIssue:fields:type:avatarId::number as avatarId,
    j[0]:outwardIssue:fields:type:iconUrl as iconUrl,
    j[0]:outwardIssue:fields:type:name as name
from data;
```

this gives:

[image]

so there is the pulling thins apart, now to push together, I would use [ARRAY_CONSTRUCT](https://docs.snowflake.com/sql-reference/functions/array_construct) over the direct string manipulation you have used, like so:

```
select  
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(
        ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(id,
            null,
            ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(
              ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(
                  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(
                    avatarId,
                    null,
                    iconUrl,
                    type_id,
                    type_name
                  )
                )
            )
        )
    )::text as output
from apart
```

but that gives `undefined` for the null, instead of empty element

[image]

but that could be resolved with a [regexp_replace](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace) to replace those

```
    )::text as output
    ,regexp_replace(output, '([\\[,])undefined([\\[,])', '\\1\\2' )
```

[image]